# Format event of Detail band executes more than once per row

Tags: ms-access, format, vba, report

This my code to alternately color rows when the data changes.
As i was researching an anomaly where a line did not change where it should i found that Access is looking at the each line more than once.

Why is it looking at the data more than once?

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

Dim test As String

If IsNull(Text158.Value) Then
    pubstrFirstDetaildata = ""
Else
    pubstrFirstDetaildata = Text158.Value
End If

If pubstrFirstDetaildata <> pubstrLastDetaildata Then
    backcolorCount = backcolorCount + 1
    If backcolorCount Mod 2 = 1 Then
        Me.Detail.BackColor = Val("&H" & "EDEDED")
        Me.Box160.BackColor = Val("&H" & "EDEDED")
    Else
        Me.Detail.BackColor = vbWhite
        Me.Box160.BackColor = vbWhite
    End If

End If

If IsNull(Text158.Value) Then
    pubstrLastDetaildata = ""
Else
    pubstrLastDetaildata = Text158.Value
End If
Text177 = backcolorCount
End Sub
```

Comment: On the line: 
"If pubstrFirstDetaildata <> pubstrLastDetaildata Then"
  where are you setting the value of pubstrLastDetaildata prior to that?

Comment: That is my mistake i have not set the value of pubstrLastDetaildata for the the first run through. and i do not get an error. i would not think that would cause the main issue do you?

Comment: I don't see anything that acts as a loop.  You've stepped through the code and have seen it process more than once?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it looking at the data more than once?

As suggested by the `FormatCount` parameter in the argument list, the `Format` event of the `Detail` band can fire more than once for a given row in the Record Source depending on what happens as the report is being rendered. For example, if the report has one or more Groups defined and one of those groups has "Keep Together" enabled then one possibility might be that

- the `Format` event fires the first time for a given row,
- as the report continues to render, subsequent rows can cause the group to spill over onto the next page, so
- the report starts a new page and "backs up" to the beginning of the group to `Format` those rows again.

If you want to ensure that the code in the `Format` event is only executed once per row then you can put it inside an `If FormatCount = 1 Then` block.